# How to trigger an alert in Javascript from PHP

Tags: php, javascript

PHP newbie here...

I am trying to trigger an alert in JavaScript from PHP, but it doesn't seem to work. :

```
if(isset($_POST['save-text'])){

        // get form data, making sure it is valid
        $submit_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $content = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['editor']));

        $new_url = 'example.com/' . $key;
        echo "<script>alert('$new_url');</script>";

        // build query
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO `source`(`id`, `key`, `submit_date`, `ip`, `content`) VALUES (null, '$key','$submit_date','$ip','$content')")
        or die(mysql_error());


    }
```

Comment: Is the if block ever entered? I'm just asking :)

Comment: yep...the code works, but the JavaScript alert doesn't show up for some reason.

Comment: You should use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of `mysql_` functions. `mysql` is deprecated.

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 3):

You can't insert HTML and JavaScript just anywhere in the page; make sure you're outputting in a location where the `<script>` tag is valid.

Comment: also script tags should say what kind of script they are.

Comment: Aren't script tags parsed and executed anywhere in the DOM? I mean, inline in the body?

Comment: I think in HTML5 you don't have to specify what kind of script it is

Comment: @Robin: Not if you're in the middle of printing an opening tag.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Lol, yes. You're answer makes sense now - "..in a location where the script tag is valid.. " :P

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">` would be better.

Answer (score -2):

your quotes were wrong:

```
echo "<script>alert('$new_url');</script>";
```

should be:

```
echo "<script>alert('" . $new_url . "');</script>";
```

Comment: Double quotes permit variable substitution in PHP. And your new code is wrong.

Comment: As @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams says, double quotes do permit variable substitution, so the existing code is OK (except it doesn't have a `type`). Your code would have to be `echo "<script>alert('".$new_url."');</script>";`, but there really isn't any point of doing that, all it does it makes it harder to read.